# Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie not working in Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity 5 Personal edition (Free) to play a .ogv movie file from `Streaming Assets` folder under `Assets`. The code is

`Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie("coc.ogv", Color.black, FullScreenMovieControlMode.Full, FullScreenMovieScalingMode.AspectFill);`

Where `coc.ogv` is the filename. The function is called on `OnMouseDown()` function. But when I try it on an Android device, it just gives a black flicker and does nothing else. There are no errors or warnings.

Please help.

Comment: I did, nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here we go. If you are building for PC, then go for MovieTexture and .ogv format. If it is for Android, go for .mp4 (h.264 under less than or equal to 480p). Use `Application.StreamingAssetsPath` to get the `assets` folder inside the `jar` file.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I found is to store the video in the `Application.streamingAssetsPath` folder and then, in runtime, copy the file into the `Application.persistentDataPath` folder and then read from there.

```
string arc = "core1280x800.mp4"; 
string defaultFilePath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, arc);
string filePath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, arc);
byte[] bytes = null;

if (!File.Exists(filePath))
{
    if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android)
    {
        WWW archivo = new WWW(defaultFilePath);
        while (!archivo.isDone)
        { } // c'mon, you can do better than this! ¬ ¬
        bytes = archivo.bytes;
        File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, bytes);
    }
    else
    {
        if (File.Exists(defaultFilePath))
        {
            bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(defaultFilePath);
            File.Copy(defaultFilePath, filePath);
        }
    }
}
Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie(filePath, Color.black, FullScreenMovieControlMode.Hidden);
```

Although the documentation only states that it is enough to have the video file on the `Application.streamingAssetsPath` folder, for days it was impossible for me to play any file, no matter its resolution nor format.  With this code I have been able to play video files fulscreen of higher resolutions than 480p and I have only tested MP4 and MOV files, but only MP4 works; MOV just fails silently.

ps. I know, the while loop is not elegant and not recommended, but for now it simple and works.